# Material Components Web and Webpack 2 not including path

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to use MDC in my `.vue` files but my build always failed because MDC does not use relative path or at least the `~`

my config looks like this: https://www.hastebin.com/pezukobuba.coffeescript

that's a snippet from laravel-mix's webpack config.

I've spent hours searching and copying other's configuration but none of them really works. I tried googling already and ran out of ideas.

Is there anyway I could use MDC using webpack 2 / laravel-mix ?